# GIT Local Corrupt Repository and Branch Deleted from Origin

Tags: git, repository, corrupt

So I have a kind of worst case scenario, I think.

I was about to push a branch to our local repo and due to some changes I had to make, pushed a branch delete of the branch in anticipation of re-pushing the branch that I was in the middle of meddling with.

In the middle of this, the power went out.

My local repo is no longer recognized as a git repo, and git fsck does nothing. The branch is not visible on origin.

Is there a way to recover from this? I see my branches in my local repo, but without being able to get it recognized as such, I cannot do anything about it.

Some options I have thought of but don't know how to implement:

Creating a new repo and somehow pulling the full repo with garbage to local and using functionality to restore my branch from garbage

Creating a new repo and somehow pulling my old branch data in manually

Assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried git cloning the repo into a seperate local folder, creating your branch there and then pasting your original repo minus the .git folder into the fresh clone?

Comment: @Smörgåsbord - I have done that separately and right now it's a plan B. I'm hoping to get my commits back as there's some additional meddling to do regarding those in order to avoid rework. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My local repo is no longer recognized as a git repo ...

First, make backup copies of whatever you have now.  Then try re-creating the `HEAD` file:

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master > .git/HEAD
```

for instance.  Then see if Git at least recognizes it.  If so, `git fsck` may be helpful, and/or there may be useful data in reflogs (for `HEAD` and/or for your branches).

Comment: re-creating the HEAD worked, and git fsck shows some dangling commits and blobs. What does this mean for the health of the repository and what action would you recommend?

Comment: The lack of any obvious corruption is a good sign.  Meanwhile "dangling commits" and "dangling blobs" are normal enough, but some of them might be ones you want to restore if their references were lost in the power failure. It's impossible to tell without information that only you have, i.e., does everything *look* right?

Comment: doing a git status showed the modified files, which looked right (except on the wrong branch, should be on mine instead of master), but after switching from master to my branch, nothing appears staged, nothing is stashed, and changing back to master shows a clean working tree which does not seem right. What happened to all the modified files I just saw before switching? Also, git log appears to have changed (before the master log looked like my branch and now it looks like master again) which is reassuring. But the modified files should have been on my branch, and now they're not even showing.

Comment: The `echo` line above tells Git that your current branch is `master` (if there's no `HEAD` file at all Git refuses to believe that the repository is a repository, so we must create one, and the contents then tell Git which branch is the current branch). `git status` consists of "diff current branch tip vs index, then diff index vs work-tree" so the output depends on `HEAD` (current branch), index contents (whatever's left after power failure—maybe intact, maybe not), and work-tree contents (whatever's left after power failure).

Comment: Thank you, sincerely, for all of your help.

Comment: If you ran `git checkout <branch>` to switch to the given `<branch>`, Git will have re-filled the index and work-tree from the tip of `<branch>`, but will have tried to do this in a non-destructive manner. In general that would mean not overwriting any index or work-tree copy of a file unless that matched the `master` branch-tip version. So probably, whatever was left in the index and work-tree, post power failure, matched the tip of your other branch.

Comment: Since you do have a backup copy of everything, you can copy that again and try with a different `echo` command to choose a different current-branch...

Comment: This looks better using the branch I was on as the current branch